# A JavaScript class constructor called inside an event callback function doesn't assign arguments' values to properties. Question is why?

Tags: javascript, reference, nan

I create an object inside an event callback function:

```
    activateStarHandler = () => {  
      document.addEventListener("starThrown", function(){
        var starView = new StarView();
        var pos = characterModel.getPosition();
        console.log(pos);
        var starModel = new StarModel(...pos);
        console.log(starModel);
        controller.stars.push({view:starView, model:starModel});
```

activateStarHendler is a method of some other class - controller. And here we have a bit of a StarModel class:

```
    class StarModel {
      constructor(positionX,positionY){
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
        this.velocity = 50;
        this.veloxityX = 0;
        this.velocityY = this.velocity;
```

So, the first snippet generates following console output:

```
    [990, 840]  [i - Value below was evaluated just now]
    0: 990
    1: 840
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)


    990 840

    StarModel {positionX: 990, positionY: 840, velocity: 50, updatePosition: ƒ, getPosition: ƒ, …}   
    [i - Value below was evaluated just now]
    getPosition: () => {…}
    positionX: NaN
    positionY: -3710
    updatePosition: () => {…}
    velocity: 50
    velocityY: 50
    veloxityX: 0
    __proto__: Object
```

The console, same as me, expected pos values to be assigned to starModel properties positionX and positionY, then evaluated them and it turned out not to be the case.

I was already blaming pos declaration and changed let to var, since it's an array, so it's values could be passed by reference (what shouldn't really happen I guess, if I'm using spread operator), didn't help.

I'm kinda saspicious about "this" usage in the StarModel constructor, since I know different values can be assigned to it deppending on way its called - how is in this case it's not really clear to me, I found a thread here where one dude stated that in case of callig constructor using new keyword it definitely should take value of constructed object, and values of other properties positionX and positionY seem to confirm.

Nothing else I can think of. Do you have any clues?

Comment: I meant ther properties THAN positionX, positionX

Comment: You have a typo veloxityX -> velocityX.  That is exactly inline with positionX being NaN.

Comment: I'm not sure what means inline in this context, but typo is in property name that I'm declating, not in the reference, so should it be a problem? and even if it was in reference JS assigns undefined in such cases.
But for reason that i don't understeand (any clarification appreciated) it solved the problem of NaN, so thank you very much. But still, positionY stayed some cosmic negative number, different one each time, each time negative.

Comment: Because at some point your program is going to mathematically calculate positionX based on velocityX but that is undefined so you will get NaN which is what you're getting.

Comment: oh yeah. :D you're so smart, thanx again.